# javascript, why you can't add onClick in HTML string, before you add this HTML string to DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, string, onclick

I need something like that:

```
function myfunc(){
   const checkbocClick = () => {
     console.log("chceckbox click")
   }

   createElement = () => {
     let isChecked = (Number(addressPoiData.notSendInfoToDriver) === Number(0))? 'checked': ""
     return `<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="sent-to-driver" onClick='checkbocClick()' ${isChecked}>`
    }
    return createElement()
}
```

This function is imported and used in one class, where the append is. But I would like to add a method at this stage to make the code more readable and clear. I don't want to use vanilla javascript because it will cause the mish you have in my code. Is there any way to do this? I've read that it's not recommended, but it doesn't work for me at all. In this version I have an error that

> Uncaught ReferenceError: checkboxClick is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

I also tried adding the checkbocClick and createElements functions as regular (not arrow) functions, changing their order, or using ${checkbocClick} in onClick. Nothing helped. I either received the error above or no response after clicking.

Comment: If you want to make it more readable, then delegate from the nearest static container instead of having inline click event handlers

Comment: And yes you can add the inline click but the function you use has to be in the scope of the page and not just the function that adds the click event handler

Comment: Lastly be sure to spell the functions correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, `checkbocClick` is visible only inside `myfunc()` function. On the other hand, when you add onclick on input, you need function that is visible  on the document level.

Instead, you can move the function `checkbocClick` outside other functions to make it visible for input.

```
function myfunc(){
   window.checkbocClick = () => {
     console.log("chceckbox click")
   }
   createElement = () => {
       let isChecked = (Number(addressPoiData.notSendInfoToDriver) === Number(0))? 'checked': ""
       return `<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="sent-to-driver" onClick='checkbocClick()' ${isChecked}>`
    }
    return createElement()
}
```

Comment: Delegation is much better. Also I already pointed the scope issue in a comment to the question

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I consoled log my checkbocClick one line before return checkbox, and it is ok. So I think function is available in createElement scope. But now I try move checkbocClick to createElement scope, and I have unfortunatelly the same error as ealier.  In the end I think i'll use delegate because it is recommended, but I wonder why onClick in string is and why I can't make it run.

Comment: @Eva yes, function is available on createElement scope. Unfortunately, we  need it available on global scope, becaue createElement returns simple string. When the element is added to the page, it will seek for function on global scope.

BTW, you can try change checkbocClick to window.checkbocClick if you need to keep this code inside "myfunc"